Find values of $a,b$. such that a matrix is diagonalizable
Find all values of $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $A$ is diagonalizable. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & a & b\\
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 2 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}.$$
So far, I have that: $$det(A-\lambda I)=\begin{vmatrix} 
-1-\lambda & a & b\\
0 & 1-\lambda & 2\\
0 & 2 & 1-\lambda\\
\end{vmatrix}=-(\lambda +1)^2(\lambda -3).$$
So $A$ has eigenvalues $\lambda=-1$, $\lambda=3$
Now, let $v=(x,y,z)^T$. Then $v\in ker(A--1I)\iff$
$$\begin{pmatrix} 
0&a&b\\
0&2&2\\
0&2&2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\iff ay+bz=0, 2y+2z=0, 2y+2z=0.$$
$$\iff y=(-bz)/a, y=-z, z=-y$$
So, $v\in ker(A--1I) \iff v=\begin{pmatrix}
x\\
(-b•-y)/a\\
-y
\end{pmatrix}=x\begin{pmatrix} 
1\\
0\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix}
0\\
b/a\\
-1
\end{pmatrix}$.
Similarly for $\lambda=3$,
$v\in ker(A-3I)\iff$ $x=(ay)/4+(bz)4, y=z, z=y \iff$ $$ v=\begin{pmatrix} 
(ay)/4 + (bz)/4\\
y\\
z
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=y\begin{pmatrix}
a/4\\
1\\
0
\end{pmatrix}+z\begin{pmatrix}
b/4\\
0\\
1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
But after this, I don't know how to find the values of $a,b$ such that $A$ is diagonalizable.

You're on the right track.
Hint Since the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is
$$c_A(\lambda) = (\lambda + 1)^2 (\lambda - 3),$$
the matrix is diagonalizable iff the $(-1)$-eigenspace of $A$ has dimension $2$, that is, if $\dim \ker (A + I) = 2$. Your computation shows that if $(x, y, z)^\top \in \ker (A + I)$, then $a y + b z = 0$ and $2 y + 2 z = 0$, and this $2 \times 2$ system in $y, z$ has a nonzero solution if and only if $a = b$.
Alternatively, we can show that $\operatorname{rank} (A + I) = 1$. Explicitly,
$$A + I
=\pmatrix{0&a&b\\0&2&2\\0&2&2},$$
and $\operatorname{rank}(A + I) = 1$ iff the second and third columns are linearly dependent, that is, if $a = b$.

+1, but: " these equations have a nonzero solution if and only if $a=b$." They always have solutions since they form the intersection of two planes (or a plane and $\Bbb R^3$ if $a=b=0$), and hence the set of solutions is either a line if the two planes are transverse ($a\neq b$) or a plane if they coincide ($a=b$).

@Didier Thanks for the comment. Here "these equations" refers to the two immediately preceding equations in $y, z$ alone, not to the equations of the $3 \times 3$ system $(A + I){\bf x} = {\bf 0}$ from which they're derived. I'll edit the answer to clarify my intent.

For the (3)-eigenspace, I have obtained: $z=4x/(a+b)$, $y=4x/(a+b)$, this implies that $a+b\neq 0$. Meaning, the matrix is diagonalizable for $a=b$ with $a\neq 0$, $b\neq 0$. Is this correct?

Since the $3$-eigenspace has dimension $1$, it cannot affect diagonalizability. But notice that $(a + b, 4, 4)^\top$ is in the $3$-eigenspace for all $a, b$. You likely divided by $a + b$ at some point to find your equations, but doing so already implicitly assumes that $a + b \neq 0$.
